# Change cssclass of button inside datalist using jquery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a button inside datalist, if I click one button have to change the css of other button in jquery.

I have more images in my page. my code accept only one "like".
I want to differentiate which one I selected.

jquery

```
function Addlike(btnlike, hdnId, term, cId) {        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CommonFunction.aspx/SaveToLike",
        data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {

            $(btnlike).attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            //  alert("Data added successfully.");

        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Unexpected error occurred.");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

aspx code

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlist" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemDataBound="dtlist_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnlike" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'><i class="fa fa-users"></i></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I just want to change other buttons cssclass. how to find the control?

Comment: use (this) it will get the current selected image

Comment: i dont want selected image. i want all the image in Datalist. because already selected button will be in green color. on select other button i want to remove color from previous one

Comment: create a class attribute for all buttons, remove the css for all the buttons and finally set the css for the current button clicked

Comment: yes. my prob is Im not able to find control id in javascript. How to find the control id inside datalist using javascript

Comment: the code you posted each function does works correctly??

Comment: yes ... code works correclty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139638/discussion-between-praba-and-sara).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chaning button color not working inside ajax call. changed like below , now working as expected.

```
$(function () {

    $('[id*=btnlike]').click(function () {
        $('[id*=btnlike]').attr("class", "btn btn-white");
    });
});
```

on click reset each button to white color.

Answer (score 0):

You can find control ID Using Jquery in following manner.

```
$('#<%= dtlist.FindControl("btnlike").ClientID %>')
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop all the LinkButtons in the DataList with jQuery.

```
$('#<%=dtlist.ClientID%> a').each(function (i, obj) {
    $(this).addClass("btn btn-success");
});
```